# hawtio needs access to github or git repo?

Tags: hawtio

When I deploy hawtio.war, I see that it pulls from github. If I use it within an enterprise, I  can configure it to use a different git repo? Does it always need access to a git repo?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy the hawtio-default-offline which does not integrate with git/maven or other online resources.